# Can't find FreeTDS data sources with pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, freetds, unixodbc

I've followed the various instructions for connecting to an ODBC data source using pyodbc via FreeTDS. I have most of it set up correctly, as I can connect to my data sources using either isql or tsql. However, when I try to access these same data sources with pyodbc, I get the error:

```
InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

My freetds.conf file contains the following:

```
[MY_DATA_SOURCE]
        host = MY_DATA_SOURCE_ADDRESS
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
```

My odbcinst.ini file contains this:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = ODBC for FreeTDS
Driver      = /opt/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup       = /opt/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
FileUsage   = 1
```

while my odbc.ini file has:

```
[DATA_SOURCE]
Driver=FreeTDS
Description=My Data Source
Trace=No
Servername=MY_DATA_SOURCE
```

where in each case the ALL CAPS are the actual names/addresses that I am using.

I am then using the following in Python:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=DATA_SOURCE")
```

Am I overlooking something obvious? I have used MacPorts to install unixodbc and freetds.

Comment: `tds version = 8.0` ... are you trying to connect to SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Why use freedts? Consider using the Microsoft ODBC driver, which is available for [MacOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15) as well as Linux and Windows. It can be used with [pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Are you using `cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=DATA_SOURCE")` ?

Comment: I am using freetds following the advice of most of the examples and guidance I've found online, including the [pyodbc docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Mac-OSX). Was using the MS ODBC driver on Linux, but the consensus seemed to be in favor of freetds.

Comment: Tried using `tds version = 7.3` as well (with no success) but was experimenting with others, again following examples.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57350910/2144390

Comment: I wonder if this is related to the fact that I am using MacPorts to install libs instead of Homebrew? Could pyodbc be looking for things in /usr/local rather than /opt/local?

Comment: I've always found it better to just be explicit with the settings and pass server, uid, and pwd. `tds version = 8.0` is not valid.